# Переводятся ли фамилии с русского на украинский и наоборот?

Tags: переводы, фамилии

Я как-то привыкла, что переводить их не следует. К примеру, если укр. фамилия — Горобець, то на русском языке пишется и произносится Горобец (не «Воробей» же!) Или, например, если русская фамилия — Воробьёв, то на украинском будет Воробйов и никак иначе. Но почему тогда в СМИ говорят: «Полина Сладкая» и «Полiна Солодка»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, конечно, украинские фамилии (и никакие другие) не переводятся на русский, если не специально поставленная цель (это должно быть оговорено) пояснить значение некой фамилии.

Имя Полiна трудновато произнести через *и восьмеричное*, мы всё равно будем слышать звук *и*, а вот если она Солодка, то Солодкой и останется.

Причём мы слышим фамилию (и склоняем) как существительное, а не прилагательное.

В СМИ много чего неправильно говорят; теперь, когда разрушен институт дикторов, на речь журналистов нельзя ориентироваться.

Answer (score 0):

Фамилии не "переводятся". Это вообще-то должно быть понятно. Фамилия погибшей девочки, судя по всему именно Солодка. В таком варианте она фигурировала даже в Российских источниках, когда уже разобрались. Попытка "перевода", согласен, не свидетельствует о большом уме авторов подобных новостных сообщений. Хотя конечно же кто-то может "слышать" по-своему, но коверкать-то фамилию зачем - в письменных текстах? Почему это все же делают, но это уже не сюда порос, имхо.

Сам эпизод разбирать не хочу.

Answer (score 0):

Фамилии не переводятся. Последнее время в интернете публикуются компьютерные переводы. Вот там и можно встретить переводы собственных имен с одного языка на другой. Думаю, что живые переводчики такого не допускают.

Answer (score -1):

Вы об убитой (якобы "фашистской хунтой") девочке? Да всё потому потому, что творцы подобных фейков исправно пользуются гуглопереводчиком, а он не знает,  что фамилии не надо переводить. Причем не факт что "переводили" на русский с украинского, могло быть и наоборот.

"Сладкая" вполне возможная русская фамилия. Какая была на самом деле, не стоит гадать. Фамилии не "переводятся", вы совершенно правильно заметили. Всё вопросы - к поставщикам новостей.

*Ольга, мы вообще-то русским языком занимаемся. Украинская тематика не должна выходить за рамки разумной необходимости. Проблемы переводов - с этим лучше на специализированные сайты.*

Comment: Просьба соблюдать нейтральность. На Украине у власти не фашистской хунта, а Полина Вячеславовна Солодка 2008 года рождения действительно погибла 8 июня 2014 г. в ходе арт обстрела Славянска.

Comment: @МаркИз вы неправы. Прошу принять к сведенью, что не считаю ваше замечание справедливым. У меня "фашистская хунта" в кавычках, так писали творцы этих фейковых новостей. Если её фамилия действительно Сладкая, значит переврали украинские источники.  Я об этом и писал, что не факт, кто тут виноват. В чем вы увидели отсутствие нейтралитета?

Comment: В единственно сколько-нибудь официальном источнике, что я нашел, фамилия приводится как "Солодка" http://pravfond.ru/media/admin/Bulleten_5_280815.pdf Так что, простите, остаюсь при своем мнении о фейковости подобного перевода.

Comment: @Мимоходов, возможно и не о ней речь. Но совершенно верно, что пользоваться онлайн-переводчиками новостным ресурсам нельзя. Здесь я полностью согласен, очень похоже, что это механический перевод. Такие ляпы очень хорошо видны даже невооруженным глазом.

Comment: Спасибо. О политике не будем, меня интересует исключительно язык.